# Fancybox is shown from jQuery UI Dialog: pressing Esc button closes both dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, jquery-dialog, fancybox-2

I have got the following issue:

A jQuery UI dialog is open, then a fancybox popup is open from that dialog.
I press Esc button and expect only the fancybox popup to be closed but this closes the jQuery dialog as well.
How do I prevent this behavior?

Comment: I think this a very good question but you have to be very familiar with fancybox to understand what the issue is. The problem is that you didn't provide any code people can hack or play with hence was voted to close. I think your approach should focus on "how to prevent an `escape` event from bubbling". I guess using either `keypress()`, `keydown()` and `keyup()` callbacks inside the `afterLoad` fancybox's callback may work to stop the `escape` propagates throughout the jQuery UI dialog ... but not sure. I haven't launch fancybox from a jQuery UI dialog before so I have to try.

Comment: Check revision here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12865254/1055987

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ closeOnEscape: false });
```

Comment: But I do want the dialog could be closed on Esc button.

Comment: can u post a link of fancy box dat u r using

Comment: +1 : it gave me the clue to sort this out. I will post the solution shortly.