# How to keep the jQuery UI dialog opened when closing fancybox using the "escape" key

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fancybox, jquery-ui-dialog, fancybox-2

This is a reformulated question from the original [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12819555/1055987)

I have a page with a [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/), and I open Fancybox from a link inside of such Dialog window.

The typical UI Dialog init is like:

```
 $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
  height: 240,
  modal: true
 }); // dialog
```

... and the typical Fancybox (v2.1.1 in this example) init like:

```
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
  closeClick: false,
  helpers: {  
   title : { type : 'inside' }
  }
 }); // fancybox
```

... so far so good, nothing special. Then the html :

```
 <div id="dialog-modal" title="jQuery UI modal dialog">
  <p>You should be able to close this UI Dialog using the "escape" key.</p><br />
  <a class="fancybox" href="images/01.jpg" title="Press the 'escape' key to close Fancybox" >Open Fancybox</a>
 </div>
```

Now, the issue is, if I close Fancybox using the "`escape`" key, both Fancybox AND the UI Dialog (from where I launched fancybox) are closed.

Both Fancybox and UI Dialog can be closed using the `escape` key but **ideally** I would like to keep the UI Dialog opened after closing Fancybox (with the `escape` key) ... if close Fancybox with the `close` button for instance, the UI Dialog remains opened.

To illustrate the issue, I created a [DEMO here](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/openFancyboxFromUIdialog_11Oct12.html).

So how can I close Fancybox using the `escape` key without closing the UI Dialog from where I opened Fancybox?

Comment: "Some down-votes are knee-jerk reactions" ... down-voting without a comment is simply unhelpful ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution :

Disable the `escape` event in both Fancybox and the UI Dialog and catch any `escape` event to close manually either Fancybox (if opened) or the UI Dialog otherwise.

In order to avoid to be closed pressing the `escape` key, both plugins offer an API option ... so for the UI Dialog add the `closeOnEscape` option set to `false` like :

```
$("#dialog-modal").dialog({
    height: 240,
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: false // disable escape event on dialog
}); // dialog
```

... for Fancybox use the [keys](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) API option like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    closeClick: false,
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    },
    keys: {
        close: [null] // disable escape on fancybox
    }
}); // fancybox
```

... then catch the document's `escape` event ( using jQuery [.keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) ) and close manually Fancybox (if opened) or the UI Dialog otherwise with this function:

```
$(document).keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        // if fancybox is opened, close it, otherwise close dialog
        if ($.fancybox.isActive) {
            $.fancybox.close();
        } else {
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog("close");
        }
    }
}); //keyup
```

See [working DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/openFancyboxFromUIdialog_fixed_12Oct12.html) and feel free to explore the source code.

Tested in Chrome v22.0.1229.94 m, Firefox v16.0.1, IE7+, Opera v11.61(1250) and Safari (Windows) v5.1.7(7534.57.2)